# Trouble updating DynamicData nuget package

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, reactiveui

Trying to update ReactiveUI but can't even get it installed correctly because of an issue with the DynamicData nuget package. Completely up to date in VS (Mac), Xamarin, Android SDK's, and iOS. I redacted some of the folder names (the ... isn't in the actual output).

The package manager shows that the most up to date version is 6.13.21.

```
Getting restore information for project .../Projects/PackageUpdateTest/PackageUpdateTest.Android/PackageUpdateTest.Android.csproj 
Getting restore information for project .../Projects/PackageUpdateTest/PackageUpdateTest.iOS/PackageUpdateTest.iOS.csproj
Running non-parallel restore.
Reading project file .../Projects/PackageUpdateTest/PackageUpdateTest.Android/PackageUpdateTest.Android.csproj.
Persisting no-op dg to .../Projects/PackageUpdateTest/PackageUpdateTest.Android/obj/PackageUpdateTest.Android.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Restoring packages for .../Projects/PackageUpdateTest/PackageUpdateTest.Android/PackageUpdateTest.Android.csproj...
Restoring packages for MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dynamicdata/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dynamicdata/index.json 177ms
Resolving conflicts for MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1...
Unable to find package DynamicData with version (>= 6.13.21)
  - Found 148 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 6.8.0.2561 ]
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'PackageUpdateTest.Android'.
```

Comment: Are you getting issues in other packages?  Do any of your csproj files have a specific dependency version your not seeing?  This usually indicates a package mismatch somewhere when sourcing dependencies.
What version are you trying to upgrade from and to?

Comment: @RodneyLittles Thanks for responding. No other current packages have this issue. I installed the dependencies for DynamicData (System.Reactive). This issue is from me trying to just install DynamicData for the first time so it's not an upgrade. It says the nearest version is 6.8.0.2561 but when you go to the nuget page (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicData/6.13.21) it clearly shows that 6.8.0.2561 is from 9 months ago and they've had plenty of updates since then.

Comment: Right.  But you're upgrading ReactiveUI.  Which takes a dependency on a version range of DynamicData.  So what version of ReactiveUI are you migrating from?  And which version are you migrating to?
This will help determine if there is a package mismatch, or maybe you are targeting a specific version and don't realize it?

Comment: @RodneyLittles I haven't even installed ReactiveUI yet. I installed System.Reactive and when I went to install DynamicData that's when I ran into this issue. If I get this issue fixed then I'll try and install ReactiveUI but currently there are no references of it in my project.

Comment: @RodneyLittles Just realized the wording of my original question is a little confusing. I’m trying to update ReactiveUI in a work project. The output I posted was from a test project I made to figure out why ReactiveUI wasn’t updating correctly. That’s when I ran into this issue with DynamicData. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: At this point everything is confusing.  What I do know is you have a package reference version issue.  Either that or you have a custom nuget feed that doesn't have the correct version.

Without knowledge of your csproj file, or however your versioning.  Not sure that I can help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

I had to run this script in Terminal (I'm on Mac) -- `nuget locals all -clear`

For clearing the NuGet cache on Windows follow these steps -- `Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> General -> Click button "Clear All Nuget Cache(s)`